# Cannot find camera

Tags: 14.04, flash, webcam

I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and my webcam (`Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:092e Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Chat`) works with Cheese* and xawtv, but doesn't work with FFmpeg and Flash (13.0.0.214) in Chrome (35.0.1916.114)

[image]

Please help me to understand why?

Comment: Can you use the in Firefox? with flash there (different version ad Chrome uses embedded version), and what are you using to test this?

Comment: Yes, I tried FireFox (29.0) and result is the same

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mp4
```

Comment: $ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.8.10-6:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:53:28 with gcc 4.8.1
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Unknown input format: 'v4l2'

Comment: i have other build ffmpeg which give me another result http://joxi.ru/q1SHUxjKTJAqH6maWVE

Answer (score 0):

type this in a command prompt:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0 chromium-browser
```

this is tailored for 64bit. command for 32bit is different. Probably like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so chromium-browser
```

Same for firefox, by replacing "chromium-browser" in the previous command with "firefox"